# Suma de un vector en MIPS(mars)

Tags: ensamblador, mips32

como podria hacer un programa que permita realizar la suma de los elementos de un vector
(A[]={1,2,3,4,5,6,7}) de 7 elementos el cual se encuentra en memoria. Y el resultado se guarde en una variable y se almacene en memoria.

Comment: Tengo el mismo problema, necesito ayuda como Trackless, he estado buscando información pero no he encontrado nada

Comment: Y que intentaste hasta el momento?

Comment: Hola Trackless, las preguntas solicitando ayuda con trabajo escolar deben incluir un resumen del trabajo que has realizado hasta el momento para resolver el problema y una descripción de la dificultad que estás teniendo para resolverlo. Lee [ask] y [¿Sobre qué temas puedo preguntar aquí](/help/on-topic) para más información.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

lo primero que tendrás que hacer es llevarte la etiqueta. La etiqueta se obtiene con la instrucción la $x, tag, de manera que:

```
la $t1 , A

Dejará en A la dirección de memoria.

Sabemos que hay 7 elementos.

li $t2, 7

Deja en $t2 el número de iteraciones del bucle que irá sumando.

li $t3,0

Éste será el contenido del contador de iteraciones.

li $t4, 0

Éste será el acumulado.

Creamos una etiqueta para volver a sumar.

for:

beq $t3,$t2,fin_for  #Si no se cumple que $t3 es = 7 sigue el bucle.

lw $t5,0($t1) # Cargamos en $t5 el contenido en la posicion 0 de la posición de memoria en $t1.

add $t4,$t4,$t5 #Acumulamos.

 addi $t1,$t1,4 #No sé si se escribe así pero vamos sumamos 4 a $t1 para ir a la siguiente posición del array, aquí es importante decir que si tienes un array por ejemplo de caracteres será un solo byte lo que tengas que avanzar y no cuatro. Los enteros ocupan 4 bytes en mips.

addi $t3,$t3,1 #Avanzamos el contador

j for #Saltamos a la etiqueta de antes si o si, arriba se hará la comprobación de salida.

fin_for:

la $t1,varResultado

sw $t4,0($t1) # Escribimos en la posicion de memoria de la variable resultado el acumulado.
```

Espero que te funcione, hay detalles de los que no se habla, debes tener en el data una declaración de un word para el resultado etc... pero vamos la idea es ésta, ánimo con el programa y disfruta de ensamblador!

Comment: Hola y bienvenido. Por favor mira [answer] y de paso haz el [tour]. Es en contra de la politica del sitio contestar preguntas sobre ejercicios, en los cuales no se ha demostrado nada. Trata de no hacer la proxima vez.